# How to remove this small button next tothe actual button/styled label

Tags: html, css, button

I have a submit Button, which I styled with a label. For some reason, a mini button for the unstyled Button remains left to the styled Button and both are clickable. The whole thing looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNQ2E.png) in the Browser. 
How do I get rid of it? I dont want to just make it invisible, because then the styled button won't be centered correctly.

```css
    [type="file"], [type="submit"]{
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 0;
    }

    [type="file"] + label, [type="submit"] +label {
      background: #f15d22;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
      font-size: inherit;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      outline: none;
      padding: 1rem 50px;
      position: relative;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    [type="submit"] +label {
      background: #2286f1;
    }
```

```html
  <div align="center">
      <button type="submit" id="send" [disabled]="!uploadForm.valid"></button>
      <label for="send">Upload & Create</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need a label-element on a button element? You can just add the label on the Button itself and style the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:none` to your button.

```
<button type="submit" id="send" [disabled]="!uploadForm.valid" style="display: none;"></button>
```

Here a short solution with inline style but you can easily add this to a CSS class.